# Running coffee script on server

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have downloaded [YouTube-Instant](https://github.com/feross/YouTube-Instant) from Github and I am trying to run it.

It includes a .coffee script file which does not run. I searched how to run a coffee script and found [running-coffeescript-in-browser](http://forgivingworm.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/running-coffeescript-in-browser/). I followed the tutorial and included the javascript file to run coffee script but still I can not run the website.

Here is the link of [my website](http://startupsandfinance.com/yt2/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile the main.coffee file with the command `coffee -c js/main.coffee` which will produce the main.js. Or, if you prefer the in-browser way it describes at the link you gave (which is not recommended), you also have to download [coffee-script.js](https://raw.github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/master/extras/coffee-script.js) and have these two lines:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="js/main.coffee"></script>
<script src="js/libs/coffee-script.js"></script>
```

But then again, only the search box will be on the page(which works but it's invisible, you have to hover to see the cursor), as it states that it is 'unfinished coffee-script port' in the github repo link.